# Limit involving iterated function $f_a(x)=x^2+a^2$

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, functional-equations, iterated-function-system

I have long ago give up trying to find a nice formula for the $n$th iteration of functions in the form
$$f_a(x)=x^2+a^2$$
However, it would be interesting to consider the asymptotic growth of the iteration of these functions. It is apparent that $f_a^{\circ n}(x)$ should behave like $\text{b}^{2^n}$, but calculating the value of the base $b$ in terms of $a$ and $x$ has been more difficult than I anticipated. We may solve for $b$ using a limit:
$$b_a(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \big[f_a^{\circ n}(x)\big]^{2^{-n}}$$
but this is as far as I have gotten, and I can’t make this any neater. The best thing I have managed to find is the rather trivial observation
$$b_a(x^2+a^2)=b_a^2(x)$$
and I have noticed that the graph of $b_a(x)$ typically looks like (but is not) a hyperbola.

Can anyone calculate any special values of $b_a(x)$ in closed form, or in terms of an infinite series or integral? Can you find any more interesting (non-trivial) functional or differential equations?

Comment: To get some idea of how complicated this can get, see http://oeis.org/A000058 and the links therein, for $f(x)=x^2-x+1$. Or http://oeis.org/A003095 for $f(x)=x^2+1$.

Comment: Had a look at those sites? Convinced?

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia, it states that the $n$th iteration of
$$ax^2+bx+\frac{b^2-2b-8}{4a}$$
is
$$\frac{2c^{2^n}+2c^{-2^n}-b}{2a}$$
where
$$c=\frac{2ax+b\pm\sqrt{(2ax+b)^2-16}}{4}$$

---

Thus, we can solve the case $f(x)=x^2-2$.

$$b_{\pm 2i}(x)=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-4}}2$$

Comment: Yes, but that's a very special case. In the general quadratic case, there's no closed-form formula.